# how to check if edittext is empty?

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I have a sign up form that asking the users to enter a username and a password twice, I want to don't submit the form and alert the user if he messes to fill any of the fields, but the button is not working in all cases, this is my code:

```
user = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.username);
pass = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.password);
pass2 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.password2);

u = user.getText().toString();
p1 = pass.getText().toString();
p2 = pass2.getText().toString();

if(!(u.equals("")||p1.equals("")||p2.equals(""))){
    btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.register2);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!p1.equals(p2))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passwords didn't match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passwords match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the ideal answer is make a method as follow:

```
boolean isEmpty(EditText e){
return e.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove this if condition line

```
if(!(u.equals("")||p1.equals("")||p2.equals(""))){
```

And put this inside the click lisner

```
if(!(u.equals("")||p1.equals("")||p2.equals(""))){
 //Toast message please enter the username or pwd
return;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is just right.  I presume this code is in onCreate.  What is happening is that your onClickListener is just never getting registered.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way is check the length of the EditText box content

```
EditText resultInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result);

if(resultInput.getText().length() > 0)
    // Edit Text is Empty
else
    // Edit Text is Empty
```

Answer (score 0):

if(!(user.getText().length() <= 0) & (pass.getText().length() <= 0) & (pass2.getText().length() <= 0))){
    btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.register2);
...